# How to pause Control Center elapsed play time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, control-center

I'm using AVAudioPlayerNode to play musics.
But, when I push pause button from Control Center, elapsed time keeps elapsing while music is paused.
I want to know how to pause elapsed time in Control Center.

And I already tried to MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate to 0, but that didn't work as expected.

```
    var info = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo
    info?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = 0.0
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = info
```

Certainly, elapsed time is paused, but it changes to 0.
I want to keeep elapsed time.

After I added a code MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime to current time, it worked well!

```
    var info = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo
    info?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = 0.0
    info?[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = musicController.getCurrentTime()
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = info
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: Double check your code, MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate to 0 is the correct way to do it

Comment: Certainly, elapsed time is paused as you say. But elapsed time changed to 0

Comment: Thank you for your response, I posted the code